# Minification of Javascript on the fly with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I use PHP to remove extra spaces and lines on the fly for HTML, CSS and javascript:-
At the start of the PHP file I use `ob_start();`

At the end of the script this :-

```
echo preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', ob_get_clean() );
```

But after this my javascript code doesn't work. I use semi-colons and brackets properly with javascript, so I wonder what is wrong in this code !
Here is a bit of my javascript, it works if I dont use the function to remove extra lines :-

```
function delfile(fileid)
    {
      var div = "f_" + fileid;
      var location = "/delfile/" + fileid;
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
                    {
                        var patt = /Deleted/;
                        var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if(patt.test(text))
                        {
                            var elem = document.getElementById(div);
                            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                        }
                    else    
                        {
                            alert('Some error deleting that');
                        }

                }
                            }
      xmlhttp.open("POST", location, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send("");
  }
```

After minifying all code on the fly, this code doesn't work ! It gives this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined files:1onclick files:1`

Minified Output : `<script>function delfile(fileid) { var div = "f_" + fileid; var location = "/delfile/" + fileid; var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { var patt = /Deleted/; var text = xmlhttp.responseText; if(patt.test(text)) { var elem = document.getElementById(div); elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); } else { alert('Some error deleting that'); } } } xmlhttp.open("POST", location, true); xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); xmlhttp.send(""); }</script>`

I guess there is some problem near `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {`.

Comment: What is the minified output and/or what does the console says?

Comment: Console says : Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined files:1onclick files:1

Comment: does it throw you that error when you try to call `show()` in console? Because the output seems to be fine

Comment: Could you post the PHP output? Because [running this REGEX](http://codepad.org/TaW3HcuT) and [using its output](http://jsfiddle.net/j3cnqwy7/) works fine for me.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto I think the problem is in another script which I added in my question.

Comment: @YashSodha Don't edit your question to show the answer. Then it can't help anyone in the future who has the same problem. Revert back your edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon after the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` so it should look like this

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  { ... };
```

Although the best advice I think is not to use such minification because you're risking unexpected errors (such as the one you're asking about). Also, I'm not sure if the few bytes you will safe are worth this extra hassle.

If you really have a good reason to minify your js/html, then I'd go for some reliable software/library to do this.

Comment: Actually, I use it to minify my whole page output, so it saves quite a 5/6 kb per page !

Comment: Well, you know best what's good for your project. Either way, good luck!